# Why doesn't sys.stdout.write work in python2?

Tags: python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def main():

    f=open("a",'r')
    line1=f.readlines()
    f.close()

    try:
        sys.stdout.write(line1)
    except:
        print "?"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You are trying to write a list to an open file descriptor. You need to write a string. I think what you're after is `line1 = f.readline()` (not `f.readlines()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.readlines()` doesn't return a single string, it returns a *list of lines*. Even if there's only one line! So `sys.stdout.write()` doesn't know how to handle that. If you iterate over that list of lines, and try to write each one, it works just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def main():

    f = open("a",'r')
    lines = f.readlines()  # lines is actually a list
    f.close()

    print lines  # You'll see your issue, here!
    try:
        for line in lines:
            sys.stdout.write(line)  # Works now
    except:
        print "?"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @KevinGuan the best option in fact, if you can, is to simply use `for line in f:` without even needing to specify. The file object itself is an iterator that will return the lines one by one. Also note that `f.read()` just reads the entire file as one chunk, but `readlines()` splits the lines into a list. So they do different things, depending on what functionality you want.

Comment: Yes I know that, I think if OP just want to print the file out, however `f.read()` or `for line in f:` is simpler than `f.readlines()` :P

Comment: Oh right, I understand. Maybe I could edit my answer to be more complete by including that option...